# NiFi registry failed to run

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to set up a Secure Apache NiFi Registry on Windows machine, following below link: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Setting-Up-a-Secure-Apache-NiFi-Registry/ta-p/247753

Unfortunately, to start the server when I am executing the command: *run-nifi-registry.bat start*

following error comes up:

**Failed to start web server: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer**

**Shutting down...**

I am unable to understand the problem, please explain and provide the solution. Thank You in advance!

Comment: need to see the full error from the log

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**: **Change the JAVA_HOME to JAVA 1.8**

Your JDK may be on higher version and new JDK does not come with JAXB classes
The

*Below is sample error log message if JDK is higher version*

```
2020-07-30 13:19:54,998 ERROR [main] o.springframework.boot.SpringApplication Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
        ... 63 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:555)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 67 common frames omitted
    2020-07-30 13:19:57,811 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.registry.NiFiRegistry Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
    2020-07-30 13:19:57,823 INFO [Thread-0] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Stopped ServerConnector@5223e5ee{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:18080}
    2020-07-30 13:19:57,823 INFO [Thread-0] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session node0 Stopped scavenging
```